# Res.json is not a function (passport.js)

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, passport.js

Today i'm coming with a brand new problem ! 
First, I have two important files :

**passport.js local signup part**

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },

    function(req, res) {
        var password = req.body.password;
        var email = req.body.email;

        var generateHash = function(password) {
            return bCrypt.hashSync(password, bCrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
        };

        User.find({
            where: {
                email: email
            }
        }).then(function(user) {
            if (user) {
                return res.json('That email is already taken');

            } else {
                var userPassword = generateHash(password);
                var data = {
                    username: req.body.username,
                    name: req.body.name,
                    firstname: req.body.firstname,
                    email: req.body.email,
                    location: req.body.location,
                    type: req.body.type,
                    password: userPassword
                };

                db.users.create({
                    username: data.username,
                    name: data.name,
                    firstname: data.firstname,
                    email: data.email,
                    location: data.location,
                    type: data.type,
                    password: data.password
                }).then(newUser => {
                    return res.json(newUser)
                });
            }
        });
    }
));
```

I'm doing an authentification part. First, I want to create an account and to use passport for it : the signup.

I'm also using Sequelize to manage my datamodels. 
But when i'm calling this localStrategy with a POST request (with my body all ok in postman) I have this error :

**Unhandled rejection TypeError: res.json is not a function** on the line 
return res.json(newUser)

Somebody can help me please?
Note that done() is not working because of passReqToCallback (but I need this to get my password and email)

Comment: are you using expressjs?

Comment: Yes sorry i forgot to tell

Answer (score 2):

You can be a little confused but passport doesn't implement signup methods. It's just authorisation library. So you must handle that use-case on your own.

First of all, create route that will be responsible for sign-up and your checks:

```
app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {

    User.findOne({ $or: [{'local.email': req.body.email},{'local.username': req.body.username}]}, function(err, user){
        if(err){
            return res.send(err);
        }
        if(user){
            if(user.local.email == req.body.email){
                return res.send("This email is already taken.")
            }
            return res.send("This username is already taken.")

        }
        else{
            var userData = new User();

            userData.local.name = req.body.name;
            userData.local.email = req.body.email;
            userData.local.username = req.body.username;
            userData.local.password = req.body.password;

            userData.save()
                .then(item => {
                    res.send("item saved to database")
                    // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
                    //res.redirect('/profile/' + req.body.username);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
                })

                }
            })

})
```

The example above is based on express framework, but you can fit it with no problems to your own case.

Next step is include passport local strategy.
    // load all the things we need
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;

// load up the user model
var User = require('../models/user');

// expose this function to our app using module.exports
module.exports = function(passport) {

```
// =========================================================================
// passport session setup ==================================================
// =========================================================================
// required for persistent login sessions
// passport needs ability to serialize and unserialize users out of session

// used to serialize the user for the session
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});


// =========================================================================
// LOCAL LOGIN =============================================================
// =========================================================================
// we are using named strategies since we have one for login and one for signup
// by default, if there was no name, it would just be called 'local'

passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
},
function(req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form

    // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
    // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
    User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
        // if there are any errors, return the error before anything else
        if (err)
            return done(err);

        // if no user is found, return the message
        if (!user)
            return done(null, false, {message: 'User not found.'}); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash
        // if the user is found but the password is wrong
        if (!user.validPassword(password))
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect password.'}); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata

        // all is well, return successful user
        return done(null, user);
    });

}));
```

};

We have only signin task now. It's simple.

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, info) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      if (!user) { return res.send(info.message); }
      req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        return res.send(user.local.username);
      });
    })(req, res, next);
  });
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your help ! I used your solution but when i'm calling the signup POST, my function doesn't end. It just shows :Executing (default): SELECT "user_id", "username", "name", "firstname", "email", "type", "location", "password", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "users" AS "users" LIMIT 1;

Comment: Same for the login*

Comment: please share your signup api

Comment: https://pastebin.com/VweCEgRC Passport.js (With the localLogin) and routes/users : https://pastebin.com/yPrGCCYt

Comment: I think that since there is no return, the function is not ending?

Comment: https://github.com/mdashikar/mevn-user-reg-module/blob/master/server/models/user.js

Comment: Link above is my model where you can see the Schema ,,, For user registration i register the data on Local Object If you don't want then you remove user.local from your code ,, just use user.name like that,,,

Comment: https://github.com/mdashikar/mevn-user-reg-module/tree/master/server  you can see my codes local User-registration setup

Comment: But I can't tell why my actual code (with your solution) is not working :/

Comment: In your signup API you are trying to save data into user.local but i think there no object call local in you db schema.

Comment: yes It was. I changed that. But I remove it now. It's still not working :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177361/discussion-between-mdashikar-and-steven-klinger).

Answer (score 1):

Passport `localStrategy` doesn't have `res` in the callback. It's req, username, password and done. Here is an example.

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true
},
function(req, email, password, done) {
    // request object is now first argument
    // ...
  }
));
```

Answer (score 1):

you are passing a string in req.json. you need to use req.send for string.
Example:

replace this line:

```
 return res.json('That email is already taken');
```

to

```
return res.send('That email is already taken');
```

if you want to sen JSON then use this one.

```
return res.json({msg:'That email is already taken'});
```

or use this condition

```
if (req.xhr) { return res.json({msg:'That email is already taken'}) }
```

Comment: Doesn't matter. `res.json` accepts string as well. You can check it in a sample app as well. it will print a pair of double quotes with it.

Comment: I don't think res.json accept only strings. please go through with this docs.
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: Yes it does. :) https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json. `The parameter can be any JSON type, including object, array, string, Boolean, or number, and you can also use it to convert other values to JSON, such as null, and undefined (although these are technically not valid JSON).`